# Unable to use DiffInDays function between birthday and now() dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-365

I have a custom field of type decimal in the contact entity. This is a calculated field representing the difference in days between the birthday field and the current date. This is the expression I am using to make the calculation `DiffInDays(birthdate, Now())`. When I try to set this expression I get this error: `You can't use Now(), which is of type dateTime, with the current function.` This is because birthdate field has `Date Only` behavior and Now() function represents a date and time fraction. Is there any way that I can get only the date portion of the Now() datetime?

Comment: This is a limitation of CRM/D365/CDS/Dataverse/<insertnextmarketingname>
"All DIFF functions require that the first Date and Time field and the second Date and Time field have the same behavior: User Local, Date Only or Time-Zone Independent. If the behavior of the second field doesn’t match the behavior of the first field, the error message is shown, indicating that the second field can’t be used in the current function."
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/define-calculated-fields#functions-syntax

Answer (score -1):

considering your are using Javascript, Convert birthdate to date object as new `Date(birthdate)` and now() with new Date() as below

```
dt1 = new Date(birthdate);
dt2 = new Date();
var diffindays = Math.floor((Date.UTC(dt2.getFullYear(), dt2.getMonth(), dt2.getDate()) - Date.UTC(dt1.getFullYear(), dt1.getMonth(), dt1.getDate()) ) /(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: I'm sure they are using a calculated field, not Javascript. I am getting the same error trying to create a new calculation using DiffInDays, too.